# Why do I get an "Error tokenizing data" error loading a CSV from my Github but no error when I load the exact same file from my hard drive?

Tags: github, loading

I'm quite new in Python. I'm trying to learn how to load data sets from different sources. I have not found the following problem on Stack Overflow or in Google searches. I have a .csv data file which I originally downloaded from a science data repository. When I load it from my hard drive there is no problem, and I can quickly get the basic facts on the data and see there are only two NaN, and no syntax errors in the column headers. When I try to load it from my Github repository I get the following:

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/hXXX/YYY/blob/master/CCCC.csv')
```

This calls the following error output:

```
Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-d5c99e7779b6> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/hXXX/YYY/blob/master/CCCC.csv')
...
...

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 75, saw 4
```

I have looked at this type of error in several Stack Overflow questions, where typing errors in the data file were found. But there are none in my csv file that I find, especially when I compare lines between the file on my hard drive and the one in my Github repository (I loaded the file into my repository from my hard drive). I got the code for loading into Python from Stack Overflow, so assume it should work. The file isn't terribly large, (3696, 22). I appreciate any help.
Thanks
Heber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are using points to GitHub's web viewer for repository contents, so the data downloaded is a web page, not a raw CSV file. GitHub uses a different URL scheme for raw file contents, you can see it by using the 'Raw' button shown in the web interface when viewing any given file. For your example, the URL would be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hXXX/YYY/master/CCCC.csv`.

Please note that GitHub does not officially provide this as a way to programmatically fetch data from its repositories, so it may not work forever.

Comment: Thanks for quick and thorough answer. This eliminated the error but then I get "HTTP 404 Error". Perhaps Github is not the best place to place my data where I can get it from the cloud. I'll do more study on loading from other urls like Dropbox.